# How to export static HTML from Svelte without Surge or Vercel?

Tags: deployment, svelte

I want to publish my Svelte web app to GitHub pages and based my application on the template https://github.com/sveltejs/template. When I run `npm run build`, `public/build/bundle.js` is created but no index.html. All the tutorials I found talk about how to deploy Sapper projects, or to use external tools like Vercel and Surge, but is it possible to just build Svelte without any external tools? All I want is a static HTML page that I can copy to GitHub pages.

Edit: See the accepted answer for the general approach, however for non-root-directory-deployment, you still need to make the paths relative. I created a pull request at https://github.com/sveltejs/template/pull/239.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In svelte, `index.html` is a static file which will import your `bundle.js` and run it.

`index.html` is located at `/public/index.html` while your `bundle.js` is located at `/public/build/bundle.js`

in svelte template, `index.html` imports `/build/bundle.js` using a script tag to initialize the application.

while deploying, you just need to upload the whole `/public` folder and everything should be operational.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me at first. I will still mark it as accepted because this was the right approach in principle, however I had to also change all root relative links (with leading slash) in index.html to relative links by removing the leading slash.